# Bash, need to change word order in multiple directories

Tags: regex, bash, directory, filenames

I have a considerable classical FLAC collection where each album is a directory. I've realized that I have used a sub-optimal structure and need to rename all the directories.

My current naming convention is:

COMPOSER (CONDUCTOR) - NAME OF PIECE

E.g.

"Bach (Celibidache) - Mass in F minor"

I want to change the naming to

COMPOSER - NAME OF PIECE (CONDUCTOR)

I.e.

"Bach - Mass in F minor (Celibidache)"

There are some possible exceptions, the (CONDUCTOR) may be (CONDUCTOR, SOLOIST)  and some directories do not have the (CONDUCTOR) part and should be left as is. The NAME OF PIECE can contain all legal letters and symbols.

All albums are located in the same parent directory, so no sub-directories.

What is the easy way to do this?

Comment: Where are you stack? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **perl** rename (some distributions have this as rename - Ubuntu and related, some as prename - Fedora and Redhat AFAIK). Check first.

```
prename -n -- '-d && s/(\(.*\)) - (.*)/- \2 \1/' *
```

- `-n` don't rename just print the results - remove after you are ok with the results.
- `--` end of the options, start of the perlexpr and files
- `-d` check that the file is a directory
- `s/.../.../` - substitution

Example:

```
[test01@localhost composers]$ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 test01 test01 4096 Feb 14 12:37  .
drwxrwxr-x. 7 test01 test01 4096 Feb 14 12:23  ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 test01 test01 4096 Feb 14 12:37 'Bach (Celibidache) - Mass in F minor'
-rw-rw-r--  1 test01 test01    0 Feb 14 12:27 'Bach (Celibidache) - Mass in F minor.flac'
[test01@localhost composers]$ prename -n -- '-d && s/(\(.*\)) - (.*)/- \2 \1/' *
Bach (Celibidache) - Mass in F minor -> Bach - Mass in F minor (Celibidache)
[test01@localhost composers]$ prename -- '-d && s/(\(.*\)) - (.*)/- \2 \1/' *
[test01@localhost composers]$ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 test01 test01 4096 Feb 14 12:38  .
drwxrwxr-x. 7 test01 test01 4096 Feb 14 12:23  ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 test01 test01    0 Feb 14 12:27 'Bach (Celibidache) - Mass in F minor.flac'
drwxrwxr-x  2 test01 test01 4096 Feb 14 12:37 'Bach - Mass in F minor (Celibidache)'
```

Note that without `-d` both the file and the directory would have been renamed.